# Table as a variable Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, ora-06550

Is it possible to retrive table name from variable in Oracle?

I'd like to do something like that:

```sql
DECLARE
    v_tab VARCHAR2(200) := adm.t4_to@wtaa;
    cnt   NUMBER;
BEGIN
    SELECT Count(*)
    INTO   cnt
    FROM   v_tab;
END;
```

When I tried to run that block I had an error:

```
Error report -
ORA-06550: linia 3, kolumna 24:
PLS-00224: object 'adm.t4_to@wtaa' must be of type function or array to be used this way
```

Comment: It's variable, so you can't select in the query. Let more details about your request.

Comment: Yep, but is there any other way to do that?

Comment: Let more details about your request.

Comment: I need a procedure with two parameters one of them should be name of the table. I don't want to write a procedure with many unions and ifs

Comment: but why you use this query?
SELECT Count(*)
INTO   cnt
FROM   v_tab;

Comment: It's just a simple exemple. Question is how to retrive table name from variable in pl/sql.

Comment: I think you can use function WITH TABLE to retrieve table name from variable

Comment: WITH TABLE in Oracle? I don't think that's right... There isn't function like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this

```
DECLARE
  v_tab VARCHAR2(200) := 'adm.t4_to@wtaa' ;
  cnt   NUMBER;
BEGIN
  Execute immediate 'SELECT Count(*) from ' || v_tab 
  INTO   cnt;
END;
```